# What is the exact function of /1 within font: 16px/1?

Tags: css

Could someone please tell what is the function of `/1` within `font: 16px/1`?

I have deleted the `/1` from the code and there seem to be more space between each line? But what is the exact function of `/1` within this context?

```
body {
    font: 16px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: it is line-height, 16px is font size and 1 is line-height

Answer (score 3):

This is the [`line-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height). The syntax of the [`font`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand) shorthand property looks like the following:

```
font: [[<'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'>] ? <'font-size'>[/<'line-height'>] ? <'font-family'>]
```

You can also use the following CSS to achieve the format of the `font` property:

```
font-size:16px;
line-height:1;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```